# Lightning Icon not changing iconName dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, lwc-dom

In my lwc html I'm using

`<lightning-icon icon-name={iconname}></lightning-icon>`

In .js setting value in icon-name on any event say platform event,

`this.iconname = 'utility:success';`

OR

I tried

`<lightning-icon data-id="icon-data" icon-name={iconname}></lightning-icon>`

with query selector in .js

`let icon = this.template.querySelector('lightning-icon[data-id=icon-data]'); icon.iconName = 'utility:success';`

but still no use

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The very simple example below works fine so I suggest you add some `console.log` statements to check that your code is executing as you think.

The norm in LWC is to drive the view from the JavaScript properties (your first approach).

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class MyIcon extends LightningElement {
    iconName = 'standard:link';
    toggle() {
        if (this.iconName == 'standard:link') this.iconName = 'standard:search';
        else if (this.iconName == 'standard:search') this.iconName = 'standard:link';
        console.log(this.iconName);
    }
}
```

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} onclick={toggle}></lightning-icon>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```